# How to display error messages in a multi-model form with transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, transactions

Two models, Organization and User, have a 1:many relationship. I have a combined signup form where an organization plus a user for that organization get signed up.

The problem I'm experiencing is: When submitting invalid information for the user, it renders the form again, as it should, but the error messages (such as "username can't be blank") for the user are not displayed. The form does work when valid information is submitted and it does display error messages for organization, just not for user.

*How should I adjust the code below so that also the error messages for user get displayed?*

```
def new
  @organization = Organization.new
  @user = @organization.users.build
end

def create
  @organization = Organization.new(new_params.except(:users_attributes))    #Validations require the organization to be saved before user, since user requires an organization_id. That's why users_attributs are above excluded and why below it's managed in a transaction that rollbacks if either organization or user is invalid. This works as desired.

  @organization.transaction do
    if @organization.valid?
        @organization.save
        begin
          # I executed next line in debugger (with invalid user info), which correctly responds with: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Exception: Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Email is invalid, Username can't be blank, etc.
          @organization.users.create!(users_attributes)
        rescue
          # Should I perhaps add some line here that adds the users errors to the memory?
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
        end
     end
  end

  if @organization.persisted?
    flash[:success] = "Yeah!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    @user = @organization.users.build(users_attributes)  # Otherwise the filled in information for user is gone (fields for user are then empty)
    render :new
  end

end
```

The form view includes:

```
<%= form_for @organization, url: next_url do |f| %>
    <%= render partial: 'shared/error_messages', locals: { object: f.object, nested_models: f.object.users } %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
        # Other fields

    <%= f.fields_for :users do |p| %>
        <%= p.email_field :email %>
            # Other fields
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

The error messages partial is as follows:

```
<% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <li><%= msg.html_safe %></li>
<% end %>
```

**Update:** Following the steps from Rob's answer I arrived at the errors partial below. This still does not display error messages for User. I added debugger responses inside the code below and for some reason `nested_model.errors.any?` returns false, while the debugger inside the controller (see above) does return error messages for user.

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>

    <ul>
      <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg.html_safe %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>

  </div>
<% end %>

<% if defined?(nested_models) && nested_models.any? %>
  # Debugger: responds with "local-variable" for "defined?(nested_models)" and for "nested_models.any?" returns true.
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <ul>
      <% nested_models.each do |nested_model| %>
      # Debugger: "nested_model" has the same values as "nested_models.any?", as you would expect. But for "nested_model.errors.any?" it returns false, which it shouldn't.
        <% if nested_model.errors.any? %>    #Initially had "unless nested_model.valid?" but then errors for User are immediately displayed on loading the form page (new method).
          <ul>
            <% nested_model.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
              <li><%= msg.html_safe %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `validates_associated :users` under your `has_many :users` association in Organization.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated

Comment: Still the same, I'm afraid, no error messages for invalid user information. There's one difference though: Sign-up form exists on `url/signup/organization`. When it renders with `new` upon invalid information, the url changes to `url/organizations`. This was always the case. When submitting the rendered form again, it processed it. With the added validation, resubmitting generates the program error: `No route matches [PATCH] "/organizations"` (only if any info included for the user).

Comment: This behavior is gone now. I posted my new, cleaned up code in the OP. I've added `validates_associated :users` to the model file. The only remaining issue is that error messages for user are not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you code successfully create a person during the rescue block?

```
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => exception
      # do something with exception here
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      @organization.users.build if @organization.users.blank?
      render :new and return
```

This code looks like it will create a new empty User regardless of incorrect validations. And render new will simply return no errors because the user was successfully created, assuming Organization has no Users.

The control flow of this method has a few outcomes, definitely needs to be broken down some more. I would use byebug and walk through the block with an incorrect Organization, then incorrect name. Then an empty Organization with incorrect User attributes.

Comment: I thought the `rescue` block only gets executed if there is an error, and otherwise it would be skipped? So, if there's an error: do the rollback on the db and re-render the form. Where in the code would you place byebug?

Comment: I'd place it before @organization.save!, then test all relevant cases. invalid org, invalid user, invalid org with empty user, etc. The console will show what is created and what the rescue block does under the hood.

Comment: It's new to me but I've made an attempt. The byebug results are added to the OP.

Comment: I've updated the OP with new, cleaned up code. It now works with the exception of displaying the error messages for user.

Answer (score 0):

organization has_many :users and user belongs_to :organization

organization.rb

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @organization, url: next_url do |f| %>
 <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @organization %>
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
    # Other fields
 <%= f.fields_for(:users,@organization.users.build) do |p| %>
   <%= p.email_field :email %>
   # Other fields
 <% end %>
 <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

In controller

```
def create
  @organization = Organization.new(new_params)
  if @organization.save
    flash[:success] = "Yeah!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
   render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: The model comments you make, I had already implemented. The `create` method as you suggest doesn't fit my needs (e.g., for a user to be signed up, validations require that an organization is saved first, as organization_id is required for a user). I tried your suggestions regarding the form but that made no difference (still same behavior).

Comment: Sure, no problem, params are: `def new_params` `params.require(:organization).permit(:name, :bag, users_attributes: [:email, :username, :admin, :usertype, :password, :password_confirmation])` `end`. Also we have the private method: `def users_attributes` `new_params[:users_attributes].values` `end`.

Comment: try this for me organization_params = params.require(: organization).permit! instead new_params @organization = Organization.new(organization_params)

Answer (score 0):

This is very related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923281/ruby-on-rails-how-to-delegate-error-messages-from-nested-model). The key is that `<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>` is, I assume, only calling the `.errors` method on the object it is passed (in this case, `organization`).

However, because the `user` errors reside with the `user` object, they won't be returned and therefore will not be displayed. This requires simply changing the view logic to also display the results of `.errors` on the various `user` models. How you want to do so is up to you. In the linked thread, the accepted answer had the error message display code inline instead of in a partial, so you could do it that way, but it would be somewhat redundant.

I would modify my `shared/error_messages.html.erb` file to check for another passed local called something like `nested_models`. Then it would use that to search the associated models and include the errors on that. We just would need to check whether it is defined first so that your other views that don't have a nested model won't cause it to raise an error.

**shared/error_messages.html.erb**

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div class="error-messages">
    Object Errors:
    <ul>
      <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    <% if defined?(nested_models) && nested_models.any? %>
      Nested Model(s) Errors:
      <ul>
        <% nested_models.each do |nested_model| %>
          <% unless nested_model.valid? %>
            <li>
              <ul>
                <% nested_model.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                  <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then you would just need to change a single line in your view:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/error_messages', locals: { object: @organization, nested_models: @organization.users } %>
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. I feel like this must be it and I tried it but it still didn't get the error messages for users. I added `debugger` in the controller before the `render :new` line, as I thought perhaps that way I could test if it indeed recognizes the `nested_models`. But entering `nested_models.any?` in byebug just gave back `undefined local variable or method 'nested_model' for #<OrganizationsController:0x007f1d63fa3390>`. If you have any suggestions how to use debug to solve why it's still not displaying the errors, let me know.

Comment: @Nick I edited slightly in case passing the instance variable makes a difference. Note, however, that `nested_models` is just a local variable inside the `_error_messages` partial (set when you called `render partial` in the view after the controller has already passed off execution to the view, so the controller isn't going to have any idea what that is. If you want to use ByeBug, you need to place it in the `error_messages` partial.

Comment: I tried it Rob, but still the same result. 1) I placed Byebug in the errors partial right after the first line `if object.errors.any?`. Byebug does not get executed at all. In other words `if object.errors.any?` is false, thereby not executing the entire partial. 2) I placed Byebug in the controller right before `@organization.users.create!(users_attributes)` and then entered that line in Byebug. It responded with `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Exception: Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Email is invalid, etc.`. So it does correctly raise errors.

Comment: I've also tried: placing the second half of the errors partial in its own seperate if statement, not inside `if object.errors.any?`. Made no difference. Next I tried with still the second half placed outside `if object.errors.any?`: opened the signup form in the browser, then placed `debugger` right after the `if defined?(nested_models)` line, submitted the form, byebug indeed started, but then don't really know what to look for. `defined?(nested_models)` returned `"local-variable"` and `nested_models.any?` returned true. `nested_models.each do |nested_model|` returned unexpected end-of-input.

Comment: And `nested_models` in byebug returned: `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: nil, organization_id: 120, email: "", etc. with all the filled in data`.

Comment: Sounds like you're most of the way there, just a syntax error I made somewhere. Now that byebug shows `nested_models` has the `user` instance in it, all you need to do is go through each model in `nested_models` and call its `.errors` method to get the errors. You may or may not need to first call `valid?` on the object in order to instantiate the errors.

Comment: Almost there indeed. By splitting the errors partial in two, I now do get the error messages when invalid information is submitted for user. One problem though, already when loading page with the form (new method in controller) it immediately displays for user a list of all errors as if an empty form was submitted instead of just loading the page with the form. It only does this for User and not for Organization. I added the code as I have it to the OP.

Comment: Calling `valid?` re-runs all of the validations and then loads an array of error messages accessed by the model's `errors` method. It seems the way the code is now, it is calling it every time, even when it's a brand new form, and therefore tries to validate a completely blank `user` object. So, is it possible to remove the `valid?` calls so that we don't reset the `errors` and therefore will only display legitimate errors? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean. I tried removing `<% unless nested_model.valid? %>` from the partial but then we're back to the original behavior: it doesn't show any error messages for user.

Comment: I also tried to replace the first line of the errors partial with `if ( object.errors.any? || (defined?(nested_models) && nested_models.any? && !nested_models.valid?) )` but that generated an error on loading of the view: `undefined method `valid?' for #<User...`.

Comment: You can't call `valid?` on a collection. I was just saying to try using `nested_model.errors.any?` instead of `nested_model.valid?` in your conditional because the latter will result in running validations on a blank object.

Comment: Ah, I understand. The result was the initial situation: no error messages for user, in any case. Using debugger returns the values for `defined?(nested_models)` and `nested_models.any?` mentioned earlier. Inside `nested_models.each`, `nested_model` still has the value that `nested_models.any?` had, as you would expect. But for `nested_model.errors.any?` it returns false! While placing debugger in the controller right after `begin` and then in debugger creating the user record, does correctly return with error messages...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a lot of untestable logic in your controller. Looks like for you logic will be better to use simple FormObject pattern.
https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects

Comment: What I want to do though is to only save if a valid organization as well as valid user get signed up (either save both or none). Also, an organization_id is required for user. In terms of requirements, this doesn't sound too crazy to me. But given these requirements there will be some custom coding necessary...

Comment: It seem to me that code organized wrong. It become untestable and unsupprotable. It is impossible to write valid tests and maintain an adequate dialogue. You have to write many letter in this post instead of simple `i expected to have :a but there is :b`. Until this moment you have to reorganize your code. It is possible that the answer is quiet simple