# Why does this integration test with post request fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing

I have written an integration test for a signup form that writes to two tables/models. It fails with the message `"Organization.count" didn't change by 1`. Is there, however, a way to see with what kind of error message the test fails (the form works in development, although there is an issue with displaying error messages, so I don't understand why the test fails). So I mean the error message you would have seen if you had done the same exact thing on the server to help me find out why it didn't save the organization/user.

```
  test "valid combined organization user signup" do
    get new_path
    assert_template 'organizations/new'
    assert_difference ['Organization.count', 'User.count'], 1 do
      post organizations_path, organization: { name: "Abc1",
                                               bag: "aef1",
                            users_attributes: [email: "test@test.br",
                                               username: "abc1",
                                               password: "foobar",
                                               password_confirmation: "foobar"] }
       end
  end
```

Perhaps the test log can help? I see here `IS NULL LIMIT` for user email and username. I don't understand why, given the test syntax...

```
Started POST "/organizations" 
Processing by OrganizationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"organization"=>{"name"=>"Abc def 1", "bag"=>"adef1", "users_attributes"=>[{"email"=>"adef1@uniqu.br", "username"=>"adef1", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}]}}
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35mOrganization Exists (0.6ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "organizations" WHERE LOWER("organizations"."name") = LOWER('Abc def 1') LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mOrganization Exists (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "organizations" WHERE LOWER("organizations"."bag") = LOWER('adef1') LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mOrganization Exists (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "organizations" WHERE LOWER("organizations"."name") = LOWER('Abc def 1') LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mOrganization Exists (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "organizations" WHERE LOWER("organizations"."bag") = LOWER('adef1') LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "organizations" ("name", "bag", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Abc def 1"], ["bag", "adef1"], ["created_at", "2015-06-27 16:28:56.179789"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-27 16:28:56.179789"]]
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.6ms)[0m  SELECT "users"."email" FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."username" ASC
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" IS NULL LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
```

The controller method is posted here: [stackoverflow.com/q/31072646/4499505](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31072646/4499505) (`organizations_path` refers to the create method)

If I compare the test log with the development log (since in development the form does work), for development it makes the post below, which seem to differ from the post in the test log. How should I adjust the test syntax to create the same post as in development?

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"***", "organization"=>{"name"=>"test60", "bag"=>"tes60", "users_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"email"=>"test60@example.com", "username"=>"test60", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}, "commit"=>"Register"}
```

**Update:** To match the development log, I changed the `post` line within the test to:

```
post organizations_path, organization: { name: "Abc def 1",
                                         bag: "adef1",
             users_attributes: { "0" => {email: "adef1@uniqu.br",
                                         username: "adef1",
                                         password: "foobar",
                                         password_confirmation: "foobar"}} }
end
```

Now in the test log it no longer has `IS NULL LIMIT` but it still rolls back and thus the test still fails with the same message:

```
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "organizations" ("name", "bag", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Abc def 1"], ["bag", "adef1"], ["created_at", "2015-06-27 19:49:45.430750"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-27 19:49:45.430750"]]
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('adef1@uniqu.br') LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  SELECT "users"."email" FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."username" ASC
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER('adef1') LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
```

Comment: Bad test data at a guess, but without the underlying code, it is a guess. Why the count didn't go up by one, depends on the underlying logic, this test doesn't care about that.

Comment: And there is no way to see the kind of error Rails got back when trying to save? Because now it's basically only reporting it hasn't saved, without giving any indication why. The underlying logic, by the way, I have posted in a seperate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31072646/4499505

Comment: Not in this test no. A test for response maybe. I'm assuming you have successful unit tests around this?

Comment: Yes, I have model and controller test that pose no problems. I have added the test log, and there for user I think `IS NULL LIMIT` indicates a problem. It seems to want to save nil values for email and username. Don't really understand why given the test syntax.

Comment: If it's not getting the email or username values, then you're probably not posting them properly. What are the model associations between `Organization` and `User`? It looks like you are posting an org with 1 user, but the param `users_attributes` makes me think you should be posting an array of users rather than a user object.

Comment: The organization model includes: `has_many :users, dependent: :destroy` `accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true` `validates_associated :users`. And the user model has: `belongs_to :organization, inverse_of: :users`. The form works in development, with the exeception of user errors: stackoverflow.com/q/31072646/4499505. The form indeed saves 1 user and the params are also set up that way (although the plural name may suggest otherwise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test code is not the same as what your development code is doing. You need to add brackets inside of the `users_attributes` array:

```
test "valid combined organization user signup" do
  get new_path
  assert_template 'organizations/new'
  assert_difference ['Organization.count', 'User.count'], 1 do
    post organizations_path, 
         organization: { name: "Abc1",
                         bag: "aef1",
                         users_attributes: { "0" => { email: "test@test.br",
                                                      username: "abc1",
                                                      password: "foobar",
                                                      password_confirmation: "foobar" } } }
  end
end
```

This is why your log says it is trying to find a user whose `email` `IS NULL`, because it wasn't able to retrieve the `email` attribute properly, so it just defaulted to `NULL` instead of `test@test.br`.

---

**Edit:** updated to match working syntax. OP was also reporting that once the syntax was fixed, there was an error with the `User` model not passing a minimum length validation on `username` which he fixed by simply using a longer username in the test data.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I added the brackets and ran the test again. It failed with the same message. The test log shows: `Parameters: {"organization"=>{"name"=>"Abc def 1", "bag"=>"adef1", "users_attributes"=>[{"email"=>"adef1@uniqu.br", "username"=>"adef1", "fullname"=>"slidaaa", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}]}}`. It also still says `IS NULL LIMIT`. I also tried it by leaving out the `[` and `]` in the test, but then got the error message `ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument`.

Comment: Sorry, I usually use Capybara for integration tests precisely to avoid these kinds of issues. I looked at the working development params you posted, it seems like it is wanting a hash within a hash, so could you try replacing the square brackets with squiggly braces, then put `"0" =>` before the inner hash so it matches?

Comment: Thanks, I changed it as described. Although `IS NULL LIMIT` is gone, it still fails with the same message. I added it to the OP.

Comment: Great, found it: username also didn't meet a validation: minimum number of characters. Only thing I don't understand is where the `"0" =>` is coming from / what it means.

Comment: I can't explain that one, except that it seems like they are replicating an array with a hash. I don't know why they would do that, but that's what it looks like. If you think about it, in Ruby, an array is basically a hash with the constraint that all keys have to be integers in sequential order. You only have one element in the hash, so it gets the "zeroth" index, or in this case, key. This would come in handy if you were creating multiple nested `User` models in your form, and I assume the following `User` would be assigned the key of `1`.